# Why is my printed date wrong?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have verified that the date is read correctly from a file, but once I use `SimpleDateFormat.format` with the pattern `"dd/MM/yy"` it suddenly adds a month. This leads me to believe lenient mode is calculating the wrong value. But I have no idea what would make it add a full month.

Some example dates I read:

```
16/09/2013
23/09/2013
30/09/2013
07/10/2013
14/10/2013
21/10/2013
```

The code used to parse the date (it's a wrapper around Calendar I made):

```
public static SimpleDateTime parseDate(String date)
{
    String[] dateParts = date.split("[-\\.:/]");
    int day = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]);

    return new SimpleDateTime(dag, maand, jaar);
}
```

The constructor used here:

```
public SimpleDateTime(int day, int month, int year)
{
    date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setLenient(true);
    setDay(day);
    setMonth(month);
    setYear(year);
}
```

The setters for day, month and year:

```
public void setYear(int year)
{
    date.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
}

public void setMonth(int month)
{
    date.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
}

public void setDay(int day)
{
    date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
}
```

And the code used to format the date:

```
public String toString(String pattern)
{
    String output = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault()).format(date.getTime());
    return output;
}
```

where the pattern passed is:

```
"dd/MM/yy"
```

Intended to print a date as:

```
16/09/13
23/09/13
```

Instead I get:

```
16/10/13
23/10/13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

January is 0 in Java; February is 1 and so on.

See `Calendar.JANUARY`, `Calendar.FEBRUARY`.

So when you're reading 1 from the file
you think you read JAN but you read FEB.

You should do: `date.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);` to fix this.

Comment: Or use the built-in constants for month names in English such as [Calendar.JANUARY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY).

Answer (score 2):

Months are indexed from 0 not 1 so 10 is November and 11 will be December.

```
Calendar.MONTH
```

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year is JANUARY; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

So if you check [JANUARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY) you see it starts in zero.

Make sure your month is in the interval 0-11. Possibly it is in 1-12.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that the counting starts at 0.

```
January  == 0
February == 1
```

and so on. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: I feel quite dumb now, having overlooked that. It is a bit confusing though, because other fields don't start at 0.

Answer (score 2):

THe problem is that you pass 9 to SimpleDateFormat and since month are indexed from 0 to 11 it will parse month '9' as the 10th month.

You need to subtract 1 from the month :)

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar` class in Java holds months starting from 0, hence when you set the month as 0, it would consider it as `January`. `SimpleDateFormat` provides for a way to correctly display the value as `01`.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format(cal.getTime()));
```

**Output:**

```
29/01/14
```

The workaround for you to align you file that `Calendar` can work with (since December - or **12** would trickle over to the **next year**) or modify your logic to pick Constants like:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by peter.petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21431005/642706) is almost correct, except for one major problem. Like your question, it neglects to account for **time zone**.

For your information, this kind of work is much easier in Joda-Time (or new java.time.* classes in Java 8). Joda-Time is so much cleaner you won't even feel the need to create a wrapper class.

```
// Specify the time zone for which the incoming date is intended.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Brussels" );
String input = "16/09/2013";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").withZone( timeZone );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input );
String output = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
System.out.println( "millis since Unix epoch: " + dateTime.getMillis() );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2013-09-16T00:00:00.000+02:00
output: 16/09/2013
millis since Unix epoch: 1379282400000
```